# Ferrys black body and mass of photon

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

We know , the black body absorbs all the radiation .
After the absorption of all the radiation, why does the mass of the black body increases?
photons don't have mass then,  how the mass of black body increases

Answer (score 1):

But photons carry energy and this energy is absorbed by the black body object so according to the mass energy equivalence principle the mass of the black body is increased.

Comment: Black body experiment is performed by Planck who lived before Einstein and the priciple of mass energy equivalence is given by Einstein

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari Doesn't mean it didn't exist, we can look at it with a modern theory and understand it.

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari ok then black holes shouldnt have existed before 1915 because Newtonian gravity cannot describe black holes they should have had the same gravity with a star of the same mass very close to the black hole.